# How can I detect light blue ID card and crop it in OpenCV?

Tags: python, opencv, computer-vision, opencv3.0

I want to detect & crop Malaysian ID card image. Please note that my priority is "not to lose information". I mean, it is okay, If in some cases, we fail to detect the ID card and keep extra image. But I don't want to delete/remove the ID card.

I am trying to first keep only blue, then find countour. But it is not working properly. I need to find good values, I tried a lot of combination. But I am unable to do it

```
img = cv2.imread('test.jpg')
lower_blue = np.array([120,110,0])
upper_blue = np.array([200,255,255])
mask = cv2.inRange(img,lower_blue,upper_blue)

contours,_ = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for contour in contours:
    (x,y,w,h) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    cv2.rectangle(img, (x,y), (x+w,y+h), (255,0,0), 10)
plt.imshow(img)
```

Comment: Perhaps use inRange() to do color thresholding on the blue color. Then morphology to close up the holes. Then get the contour.

Comment: Already doing inRange,

Comment: I've removed the questionable use of personal details. If you want to provide a sample of the kind of image you're trying to process, post an anonymised image or a sample image of an imaginary person. Even with an image though, at this point I feel the question is too broad to be reasonably answerable either way.